# Retrieve data attribute of a selector class as an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, attributes, html-table

I am running a PHP + JQuery + DataTables page. Everything went fine and I have a similar mark up from the following:

```
.......
<tbody>
    <tr data='1'>
        ....
    </tr>
    <tr data='2'>
        ....
    </tr>
    <tr data='1'>
        ....
    </tr>
    <tr data='8'>
        ....
    </tr>
    <tr data='2'>
        ....
    </tr>
    <tr data='7'>
        ....
    </tr>
    <tr data='7'>
        ....
    </tr>
    .
    .
    .
</tbody>
```

I need to get all the `data` attribute of all the `tr` in an `array`, well in the case of the above table, its:

```
var data_values = [1, 2, 8, 7];
```

I think that the logic may somewhat starts with `$('tr').attr('data')` but it returns `undefined`. I've performed already a query to the database and it also returns an `array`:

```
var database_returned_values = [2, 8];
```

My goal from the start is to remove the `tr` elements that are not found in the `database_returned_values` array. My solution is to subtract `database_returned_values` array from `data_values`. The difference will be the `tr`s to remove. But I cannot even start to fetch `data_values`. How can I retrieve the `data` attributes of all `tr` and put it in an `array` or are there any easier way to do this?

In this case, the `tr`s to remove are those which have `data` attribute of `[1, 7]`;

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/rb00j1wn/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `each()` to iterate all the `tr`:

```
var data = new Array();

$("table tbody tr").each(function(){
   if($.inArray($(this).attr("data")) == -1) // check if not in array
       data.push($(this).attr("data"))
})
```

Comment: Yes, it does. What he can do is check if the item already exists inside the each() callback function or after it, remove the duplicates.

Comment: @GideonApolloBardelas added to check before added in array

Comment: You should not be using `attr("data")`

Answer (score 1):

The `data` property needs to have something after it.

`<tr data-id='7'>`

And then jQuery has a nice method you can use called `data`.

`$("tr").data("id")`

Answer (score 0):

You can get all the trs, then iterate them. Then, you have to read the data-* attribute (you should'n use only data="anything") and add to an empty array. Then, remove duplicates.

As long as you are using jQuery, you can do this with:

```
<table>

    <tr data-id="1"></tr>
    <tr data-id="3"></tr>
    <tr data-id="1"></tr>
    <tr data-id="4"></tr>
    <tr data-id="4"></tr>
    <tr data-id="7"></tr>
</table>

var ids = [];
$("table tr").each(function(index, item) {
    ids.push($(item).data("id"));
})

alert($.unique(ids));
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/chrisbenseler/s8pytwdz/

Then, iterate this new array ($.unique(ids)) and check whatever you need to check.